# Overlapping panels on top of Main frame

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I'm trying to get 3 different panels to overlap eachother.

Simple description: 
 I've got a simple map and on top of this map I need a Compass and a few Textfields.

What would be the best approach in fixing this issue?

On desktop.

(Java)

Comment: In which platform do you want to do this? Android, Web, desktop?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java Swing - how to show a panel on top of another panel?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/852631/1048330)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question and you can indeed. You need to use the [JLayeredPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html). From the looks of things it works similar to ordinary panes except you can specify which *layer* certain components reside.